# Package extlinux only partially installed, causing package installation and apt update problems

Tags: apt, package-management

I've been running 12.04 x64 LTS desktop for about a year with no issues, but recently I've done something - no idea what - that that appears to have resulted in a broken or partially installed extlinux package.

Now most of the apt installs or daily updates I run either fail or partially fail, with errors similar to below.

I've tried `apt-get clean`, `apt-get autoclean`, using the aptitude ncurses interface to find broken packages (no results) and to complete the installation of partially-installed extlinux (fails with the error below), no luck.

Anyone know what might be the problem and how to fix it?

```
$> aptitude

(Reading database ... 681145 files and directories currently installed.)

Removing libio-pty-perl ...

Removing libllvm3.0:i386 ...

Removing linux-headers-3.2.0-31-generic ...

Removing linux-headers-3.2.0-31 ...

Removing sdparm ...

Removing ttf-umefont ...

Removing ttf-unfonts-core ...

Removing wine-gecko1.7 ...

Removing wine-gecko1.7:i386 ...

Removing wine-mono0.0.4 ...

Processing triggers for man-db ...

Processing triggers for libc-bin ...

ldconfig deferred processing now taking place

Setting up extlinux (2:4.05+dfsg-2) ...

P: Checking for EXTLINUX directory... found.

P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-51-generic...

P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-49-generic...

P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-48-generic...

P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-45-generic...

P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-44-generic...

P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-43-generic...

P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-41-generic...

P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-40-generic...

P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-39-generic...

P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-38-generic...

P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-37-generic...

P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-36-generic...

P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-35-generic...

P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-34-generic...

P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-33-generic...

P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-32-generic...

P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-31-generic...

P: Writing config for Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda1...

P: Writing config for Windows Recovery Environment (loader) on /dev/sda2...

P: Installing debian theme...cp: cannot stat `/usr/share/syslinux/themes/debian-squeeze/extlinux/memtest.bin': No such file or directory

dpkg: error processing extlinux (--configure):

subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1

No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

Errors were encountered while processing:

extlinux

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

A package failed to install.  Trying to recover:

Setting up extlinux (2:4.05+dfsg-2) ...

P: Checking for EXTLINUX directory... found.

P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-51-generic...

P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-49-generic...

P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-48-generic...

P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-45-generic...

P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-44-generic...

P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-43-generic...

P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-41-generic...

P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-40-generic...

P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-39-generic...

P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-38-generic...

P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-37-generic...

P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-36-generic...

P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-35-generic...

P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-34-generic...

P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-33-generic...

P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-32-generic...

P: Writing config for /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-31-generic...

P: Writing config for Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda1...

P: Writing config for Windows Recovery Environment (loader) on /dev/sda2...

P: Installing debian theme...cp: cannot stat `/usr/share/syslinux/themes/debian-squeeze/extlinux/memtest.bin': No such file or directory

dpkg: error processing extlinux (--configure):

subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1

Errors were encountered while processing:

extlinux

Press return to continue.
```

Comment: apt-get remove --purge extlinux
apt-get install extlinux
apt-get clean && apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get dist-upgrade -y thanks works for me!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was installed with [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) as a dependency.  Only needed UNetbootin temporarily to make an install USB, after that was done, no need to keep it installed.

`sudo apt-get purge unetbootin` fixed it, no side effects.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I was able to resolve it using the following commands:

```
apt-get remove --purge extlinux
apt-get install extlinux
apt-get clean && apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get dist-upgrade -y
```

And it worked! Might help someone. Thanks.